# How can i remove a XML Element on JSON schema generated by swagger

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, swagger, openapi

I'm looking to generate a **JSON** schema from model (java) with swagger.
Actually shown on swagger a XML Element (don't need it)

[image]

i want remove it without remove annotation like @XmlElement or @XmlType

Must be like this one:

[image]

Exactly i need to remove this part (XML Representing):
[enter link description here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/representing-xml/)

Comment: You'll probably need to post-process the generated OpenAPI file (e.g. using an OpenAPI parser or a YAML parser) and remove `xml` elements from schemas.

Comment: Could you share this part of the code? When you generate the string Json?

Comment: @LucianaOliveira I generate my classes with jaxb from xsd.
This part is removed when i remove 
XmlAttribue, XmlElement and XmlType annotations. there is something to do without removing those annotations ?

Comment: Yes, there is. I think you are using java 6. If your Json Schema is in a String type, you can use the method `... .replace("xml","");` Could you confirm the type of the json variable? I saw a JAXB code to try to understand your problem and most of variable are String type.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.